# $con.Open() doesn't work in foreach, but works when directly used

Tags: sql-server, powershell, foreach

I have a code snippet that is used to connect to a SQL Server Instance, and query, this works fine.

```bsh
$instance="Instance"
$DB = "master"
$sqlConnection = ConnectionString $Instance $DB
$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($sqlConnection) 
$sqlConnection.Open()
```

However, the same code snippet, if put into a foreach loop, where it has to iterate through a set of servers, it doesn't work.

```bsh
foreach ($instance in $Instances) {
    $instance
    $DB = "master"
    $sqlConnection = ConnectionString $Instance $DB
    $sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($sqlConnection) 
    $sqlConnection.Open()
}
```

Error:

> Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

Comment: Don't use the same veriable for different things (here: `$sqlConnection` for both the connection string and the connection object). Check the connection string before opening the connection. Also, what does the function (?) `ConnectionString` actually do?

Comment: At least close the connection before you open a new one using the same variable name.

Comment: Please look into using `Begin` `Process` `End` to re-use such connections.  As a bonus, you want to close the connection within the `End` block.

Answer (score 0):

Ansgar is correct. You shouldn't reuse variable names.

An easier way to implement this is using [the Invoke-Query module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/InvokeQuery/0.9.1), which collapses most of your code to a single line.

```
$sql = "Update myTable set myColumn = 1;"
$db= "master"
$instances = ("instance1","instance2")
foreach ($instance in $instances)
    ## This command uses windows auth. 
    ## You can pass in a Credential object to use SqlServer auth.
    $rowcount = $sql | Invoke-SqlServerQuery -Server $instance -Database $db -CUD
   Write-Host "Updated $rowcount rows on server $instance."
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the module.

Comment: I feel, there is some different issue while I run these kinds of commands from foreach. All those run if I run directly, but, not when they are called under foreach. Please guide me through.

Comment: The the Invoke call should work fine inside the foreach loop. What errors/behaviors are you seeing? Can you post more example code that is causing you problems? 
(side note: I just corrected a typo with the rowcount variable name. Was that an issue?)